# Angular SPA uses a lot of memory in browser

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application

I have a single page application built with Angular and UI-router. When clicking around I noticed the site getting slower and since I installed the Firefox addon "Tab data" to monitor the memory of each tab I noticed a significant increase of memory usage building up (starting at 20MB and going over 200, still within the same SPA).

I have no idea whats cousing it, and no idea where to start looking. Can it be overusage of other bower librarys? (I have about 15 atm) Or can it be something within Angular itself, like directives?

Also, is there a better way to debug memory issues using Firefox and Firebug (on windows)?

Comment: Please show us the controller js and html code of the page with more memory usage

Answer (score -1):

When you are developing code through Angular js then you will be using large number of external libraries with it.

1. When you add those libraries to the source code then try to add the
   minified version of those libraries.
2. Also you can use grunt or gulp to minify the whole front-end code to a single javascript file so that loading time of the website decreses and also the cumulative size of javascript file decreases.
3. when you develop your angular code for minification then it should be written down in proper syntax line

   ```
   var app = angular.module('bigApp', []);

   app.controller('mainController', ['$scope','$http',
   function($scope,$http) {

       $scope.message = 'HOORAY!'; 
   }]);
   ```

Here when you minify then $scope will get converted to a and $http will be converted to b. this is just an high level example

For better minification knowledge you can refer

https://scotch.io/tutorials/declaring-angularjs-modules-for-minification

Comment: Beside this answer is outdated - now-a-days we use Angular instead of angularJs, it has a wrong assumption, that we use a large number of external libraries. Libraries, modules can be used lazy ways, even async script tag is supported natively. minification is not the only way to achieve to solve the problem. it is a workaround.